# Show the following series converges or diverges using the comparison test.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(\frac{n}{n+2})}^{n^2}$.
I'm relatively certain it converges, but I'm not sure how to prove this. It was suggested that I try and use the comparison test, but I'm not sure which series I could use to compare it with.

Comment: WA says that it uses the ratio test. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28n%2F%28n%2B2%29%29%5E%28n%5E2%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1+\frac{2}{n})^n\ge 1+\frac{2}{n}.n=3$

It follows that, $(\frac{n}{2+n})^{n^2}\le \frac{1}{3^n}$

Comment: I'm a little confused how you derived the first line : $(1+\frac{2}{n})^n\ge 1+\frac{2}{n}.n$

Comment: @Kyle its the binomial theorem $(1+x)^n \ge 1+ {n\choose 1}x + {n \choose 2}x^2 + .. \ge 1+nx$

Comment: Even easier, @Kyle: it is Bernoulli's Inequality.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$a_n:=\left(\frac n{n+2}\right)^{n^2}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n^2}}\implies$$

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac2n\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^{-2}$$

Comment: Apparently someone didn't like my answer....oh, well.

Comment: Personally I like it.+1

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor series we prove easily the convergence of the series by comparison:

$$\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^{n^2}=\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{-n^2}=\exp\left(-n^2\log\left(1+\frac2n\right)\right)\sim_\infty e^{-2n}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$